# python/cv2: create 2d matrix of pixels of a certain color

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I have got this array:

```
color_matrix = numpy.empty((5,5,3), numpy.uint8)
```

and this color

```
color = (255,255,0)
```

and I want to assign the color to every "pixel" of `color_matrix` (I presume the third dimension represents a pixel). How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
color_matrix[:] = 255, 255, 0
```